# Selenium Drag And Drop не работает на Jenkins

Tags: java, selenium, selenium-webdriver, jenkins

Проблема в следующем:
Есть автотест который должен выполнять Drag&Drop элементов в определенном порядке.
Drag&Drop реализован в тесте следующим образом:

```
Actions builder = new Actions(driver);
Action dragAndDrop = builder.clickAndHold(dragable)
                  .moveToElement(dropable)
                  .release(dragable).build();
dragAndDrop.perform();
```

Так же пробовал и другим способом:

```
Action dd = builder.dragAndDrop().build();
```

Так вот, через IDE когда запускаю все работает, он перетаскивает как надо.
Когда запускаю на Дженкинсе(ВАЖНО: Дженкинс запущен через командную строку!!!) все тоже нормально, все работает.
Но!!! Когда запускаю на удаленном Дженкинсе(который запущен как Windows Services) то он никак не хочет перетаскивать. Просто ничего не происходит.

Надеюсь на вашу помощь!

Я использую Java, Selenium WebDriver, TestNG.

Comment: что значит ничего не происходит? что выдает?

Comment: Вот именно что ничего и не происходит, ничего не выдаёт, по логам он как будто выполнил перетаскивание, а по факту ничего не сделал.

Comment: попробуй `new Actions(Browser.getDriver()).dragAndDrop(fromElement, toElement).build().perform()`

Comment: Это не работает

Comment: что именно не работает? опишите все подробнее

Comment: Перетаскивание элементов не происходит(Drag&Drop). Когда тест доходит до места перетаскивания элементов, он его выполняет, а по факту в браузере операция перетаскивания не выполняется.
Повторюсь, что один и тот же код, работает через IDE, и через Jenkins запущенный через командную строку. А через Jenkins запущенный как Windows Services он не работает. Один и тот же код!!!

Comment: как Windows Services вы запустили от системного пользователья ? попробуйте запустить сервис от того пользователья, который запускает через cmd

Comment: И так и так пробовал